# Windows Performance Counters ASP.NET Apps: Why is my www-service instance not visible?

Tags: iis, iis-6

A customer is complaining that one Web-based tool is loading very slowly, and I would like to monitor Request Execution Time using Administrative Tools / Performance. So I select ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727 as the Performance Object and Request Execution Time as the Performance Counter. However, in the "Select instances from this list", I cannot find the instance ID of my web site. The web site is on HTTPS---could that be the problem? Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question: The site itself was stopped, and thus didn't appear in the instance list.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, this will occur if a site is stopped.  The information in performance monitor is real-time and there is only a w3wp.exe worker process for the app pool if it not only started but has received some traffic to cause it to spin up.

Further to that, it's not just when the site is stopped that you need to worry about that.  The performance objects are defined per PID.  The PID changes whenever the app pool recycles, which is a common occurrence in IIS, so if you are watching a process in perfmon, make sure to update it often, or use something like System Center Operations Manager which can maintain the app pool to PID mapping for you.

As a side, if you haven't already, here's how to have the PIDs show up in perfmon: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2007/03/19/registry-change-for-perfmon-and-pid-data.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! If you can explicitly mention the point about stopped sites missing from the list, I will vote up your answer and mark it as the accepted one, since it's more comprehensive than mine.

Comment: Sure. I added a paragraph mentioning that and also details on why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the registry change for the pid in perfmon then you can find the pid back through the system eventviewer.

A worker process with process id of '[pid]' serving application pool '[app pool]' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.